# HTML Table Borders are larger when setting specific border size

Tags: html, html-table

I have a set of HTML table where I configured the border as per the following

Screenshot of current table settings:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AegWX.png]

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="box-shadow: none; border: 3px solid black; border-bottom: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 80px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: left; font-size: 20px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Test 1</td>
    <td style="border-left: 3px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width: 900px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right:10px; text-align: left; font-size: 18px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>

    </td>
    <td style="box-shadow: none; border-left: 3px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width: 125px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Test 2</td>
    <td style="box-shadow: none; border-left: 3px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width: 200px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Test 3</td>
    <td style="box-shadow: none; border-left: 3px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width: 125px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Test 4</td>
    <td style="box-shadow: none; border-left: 3px solid black; border-right: 3px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width: 500px; padding-left: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">Test 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can tell from the screenshot, that the borders that were configured turned out to be slightly thicker than the ones above it. However, they are all using border 3px solid black, except the one above is not using any border-right / -left concept, but just border:3px solid black;

I screenshot it further in paint zoomed in, and saw that there were actually extra thicker lines for the above settings.

Zoomed in

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE07E.png]

Any suggestion to make it consistent?

This is what happens when I set my borders to just 3px solid across the board instead of doing -left. However, I need the bottom border to be blank so I set borders specifically
[image: Border 3px solid black across]

And the very moment I set the Test 1's td to border: 3px solid black; border-bottom: 0px; My outcome is that the right, left and top gets thicker again.

[image]

Comment: You are setting `border` for Test 1 instead of `border-left` like you do for the rest. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. No, I was just testing around to see if what exactly is affecting an extra bit of shading / pixel on my border. Having set it to border-left outcome is still the same. 

It seems that only if I use border: 3px solid black across all my borders, will the borders be consistent, but I can't do that cause there are lines that I need to be hidden.